# How to use getById method to get the a corresponding name in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning Spring MVC and I want find a car via an `id` but get in return the `name`.

In my service class I call a generic method `getXXXById`. This is something JPA gives me by nature.

I know that I get the whole entity but how can I just receive the corresponding `name` to the `id`.

Example: I call `getCarById(2)` and it gives me back `Tesla`.

**My Table:**

```
id | Name 
----------
1  | Ford      
2  | Tesla
```

**My Service:**

```
class CarService {

// code ...

public Optional<CarEntity> getCarById(int id) {
    return carRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to do that.

### Making your own query

You could write your own query in JQPL to retrive only names.

For example you could create method like that in your repository.

```
@Query("select t.name from CarEntity where id = ?1")
public String findNameById(Integer id);
```

more information on this feature of Spring Data Jpa [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

### Projections

Second option is to make projection. As it is written in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

> Spring Data query methods usually return one or **multiple instances** of the aggregate root managed by the repository. However, it might sometimes be desirable to rather project on **certain attributes of those types**. Spring Data allows to model dedicated return types to more selectively retrieve partial views onto the managed aggregates.

In simple words, it allows you to aggregate your results form queries in some limited set of attributes rather then whole entity.

Specifically for your needs I'd suggest to use first approch, but it is worth to know both.